# Ext JS Grid Filters in Header checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to implement filtering in my grid.Panel component. The filtering works fine (date, string and numbers) but I can not uncheck the "Filters" checkbox by clicking on it. As far as I have seen in the Ext js documentation there is nothing that I should add extra to be able to uncheck the Filters checkbox (see image below)
[image]

When I click on the Filters checkbox, nothing happens, no error also. The only way to disable this particular "Wholesaler" filter is if I go to the text box and remove the entry. This of course would be just fine, but at the date filters, I also can not click the checkbox and thus can not remove the filter once applied (see image below) The only way to remove it is to refresh the page.
[image]

I am using Ext JS version 5.1.2, and here is the sample code:

```
        {
            dataIndex: 'Wholesaler',
            text: 'Wholesaler',
            filter: {
                type: 'string'
            },
        }
```

And the Panel componenet itself:

```
Ext.apply(this, {
        region: 'center',
        api: new Dextop.api('sample'),
        border: false,
        plugins: 'gridfilters',
        columns: sample.getController().getGridColumns(),
        storeOptions: {
            autoLoad: false
        }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you receiving any error messages from the browser on uncheck the filter?

Comment: @FabioBarros No messages at all